# Emacs org: specify R session?

Tags: r, emacs, org-mode

How can specify the session to use for evaluating source blocks when there are multiple R sessions? Say I have two sessions open, *R* and *R:2*. Then this

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :sessions *R*
ls()
#+END_SRC
```

Should evaluate ls() in session *R* whereas

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :sessions *R:2*
ls()
#+END_SRC
```

Should do the same in session *R:2* -- but it is evaluated in session *R*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example will work exactly as you have it with one minor change:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R*
ls()
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R:2*
ls()
#+END_SRC
```

Or to make it slightly clearer:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R*
wd <- getwd()
print(paste0("Current working dir: ", wd))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Current working dir: /private/tmp/one

#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R:2*
wd <- getwd()
print(paste0("Current working dir: ", wd))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Current working dir: /private/tmp/two
```

Comment: Thanks! My bad -- nude sure why I did not see this.